# how to find the no of identical items in a table?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

i am developing a web app in Django,using python.i have two classes one for item and other one for item  details.i would like to count the similar models in item details table and display it as total quantity for that model in item  table whenecer an itemdetails is created.below are my models.

```
class Items(models.Model):

model_no= models.CharField(max_length=30,null= True )
description=models.CharField(max_length=50,null= True )
total_qty=models.IntegerField(default= 0,null= True )
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())


class ItemDetails(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('In-Stock', 'In-Stock'),
    ('Out-of-Stock', 'Out-of-Stock'),
    ('issued-to', 'issued-to')
)
serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
rem_qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='in-stock', choices=STATUS)
model_no=models.ForeignKey(Items,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
issued_to =models.ForeignKey(Prosecutions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
employee_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code. More info about an MCVE can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: i have included my models above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the answer for my question.it took some time but i have reached the solution as per my requirement.

```
    def calc_total_qty():
for item in Items.objects.annotate(itemdetails_count=Count('itemdetails')):
    item.total_qty = item.itemdetails_count
    item.save(update_fields=['total_qty'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a relationship between the models similar to the one below.

```
class Items(models.Model):
   name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

class ItemDetails(models.Model):
   name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If so, you can access the number of ItemDetail objects connected to the specific Item object with the following query.

```
item = Items.objects.get(id=1)
item_count = item.itemdetails_set.all().count()
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply.i have tried your code but it says "ItemDetails' object has no attribute 'item_set'.below is what i tried                      "itemdetails=ItemDetails.objects.get(id=15)
    item_count = itemdetails.item_set.all().count()
    print(item_count)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I updated the answer correctly. ItemDetail objects can only have a relation to only one Item object. So we need to send this query with the Item object.

Comment: can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Of course, let's say there is an Items object. Like `item = Items.objects.get(id=1)` . You can get the number of ItemDetails objects which are linked to this object with the following query. `item.itemdetails_set.all().count()`. In a reverse relation, an ItemDetails object can only link with only one Item object. For example `item_detail=ItemDetails.objects.get(id=1)` `item_detail.model_no` will return that one object. For more information about the Many to One relationship, you can read this documentation. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/One-to-Many-or-Many-to-One-Relationship-in-DBMS

Comment: thanks bro,its working.has solved my problem nearly half.the other half is ,can i use the same to update the total_qty on database and save the value to database each time an itemdetail is created.?

Comment: Yes you can override the save method of ItemDetail class for that, like `def save(self, *args, **kwargs): if self.id is None: self.item.total_qty += 1 self.item.save() super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I took a screenshot to make it clearer. https://pasteboard.co/JC7TY96.png

Comment: getting the following error.uploaded the screenshot.https://pasteboard.co/JC84XFN.png

Comment: Can you change self.model_no instead of self.item

Comment: i have implemented another solution which utilizes a function to meet my requirement.i don't know how effective or performance degrading this would be if it is a huge database.i will call the function each time an item is created or deleted ,which would update my total_qty field.here are the screenshots.https://pasteboard.co/JCkOmbW.jpg https://pasteboard.co/JCkOZLI.jpg https://pasteboard.co/JCkPnJf.jpg https://pasteboard.co/JCkPSeU.jpg